# KoaJS with Thunkify + Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose, thunk

I'm working on my first koajs project and after understanding (or trying to) generator functions, yield, thunks etc. I'm running into a problem with mongoose (on which I heavily rely). After searching the forums, the solution was thunkify:

**CoffeeScript:**

```
Controller = require './basecontroller'
User = require '../models/user'

UserController = ((c, User) ->
  return (
    get: (next) ->
     userQuery = c.libs.thunkify User.find
     try
       users = yield userQuery {}
       @body = users
       return
     catch e
       console.error  "Error: #{e}"
       throw e
       return
     next()
  )
) Controller, User

# Export functionality
module.exports = UserController
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.8.0
var Controller, User, UserController;

Controller = require('./basecontroller');

User = require('../models/user');

UserController = (function(c, User) {
  return {
    get: function*(next) {
      var e, userQuery, users;
      userQuery = c.libs.thunkify(User.find);
      try {
        users = (yield userQuery({}));
        this.body = users;
        return;
      } catch (_error) {
        e = _error;
        console.error("Error: " + e);
        throw e;
        return;
      }
      return next();
    }
  };
})(Controller, User);

module.exports = UserController;
```

which makes sense in my head ... but I'm receiving this error:

```
14:56:01 web.1  | Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'discriminatorMapping' of undefined
14:56:01 web.1  |   TypeError: Cannot read property 'discriminatorMapping' of undefined
14:56:01 web.1  |       at find (/Users/mial/Projekte/MiPa/schuppen4-on-heroku/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:940:18)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mial/Projekte/MiPa/schuppen4-on-heroku/node_modules/thunkify/index.js:43:12)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at next (/Users/mial/Projekte/MiPa/schuppen4-on-heroku/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:90:21)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mial/Projekte/MiPa/schuppen4-on-heroku/node_modules/koa/node_modules/co/index.js:45:5)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at Server.<anonymous> (/Users/mial/Projekte/MiPa/schuppen4-on-heroku/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:125:8)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:111:23)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at Socket.socketOnData (_http_server.js:343:22)
14:56:01 web.1  |       at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
```

... umm. Help? :)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it :)

```
Controller = require './basecontroller'
User = require '../models/user'

UserController = ((c, User) ->
  User.find = c.libs.thunkify User.find
  return (
    get: (next) ->
     try
       users = yield User.find {}
       @body = users
     catch e
       console.error  "Error: #{e}"
  )
) Controller, User

# Export functionality
module.exports = UserController
```

Apparently I had to "overwrite" the User.find function and define the thunkify before my module pattern `return` statement.

---

**Update**: No need to use thunkify with mongoose. You can just use the `exec` function since it is already a <strike>thunk</strike> promise, which `co` also works with (thanks @jmar777):

```
Controller = require './basecontroller'
User = require '../models/user'

UserController = ((c, u) ->
  return (
    get: () ->
     try 
       users = yield u.find({}).exec()
       @body = users
     catch e
       console.error e
  )
) Controller, User

module.exports = UserController
```

Comment: Small correction: [`.exec()` returns a Promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec), which `co` also works with.  Glad you got it working, though :)

Comment: Awesome - getting closer to understanding all the generator magic :D Thank you @jmar777 !